# Powershell: how to fill Placeholder (Variables) from an external HTML-Document?

Tags: powershell

I want to send an HTML-Email with Powershell and the `Send-MailMessage` Function. To keep my Code lightweigt, I have placed the HTML-Code for the Mailbody outside my Powershell-Code.

The challange is, to replace the Varibales inside the HTML-File with Powershell variables before sending the E-Mail.

The code here is not complete. I have shortened it to clarify the problem.

**body.htm**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> Hello $Salutation! </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**myscript.ps1**

```
$MailBody = Get-Content body.htm -Raw
$Salutation = "Foo Bar!"
    
$MailMessageParam = @{
            "Subject"     = "Mail from Powershell!"
            "Encoding"    = "UTF8"
            "Body"        = $MailBody
            "BodyAsHtml"  = $true
        }

Send-MailMessage @MailMessageParam
```

My Problem is, that the Variable `$Salutation` will not be filled. The `$MailBody` Variables behaves like a Passthrough. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution I can think of is to replace the *`$Salutation`* with a placeholder and use the format operator to format it. So change *body.htm* to

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> Hello {0}! </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And then in the hashtable(*`$MailMessageParam`*) set,

```
"Body" = ($MailBody -f $Salutation)
```

Alternatively you can just use [*`ExpandString`* method which returns a string with all of the variable and expression substitutions done.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandinvocationintrinsics.expandstring?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#definition)

```
"Body" = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($MailBody)
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($MailBody)` solved it!